# Google Query URL Minimum parameters required

Tags: google-api, google-search-api

I have been searching for a while now without success for the minimum google search parameters needed for a search string in a url.

Right now if I want to create a search url for the keyword hello ... i need:

```
https://www.google.com/#hl=en&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=hello&oq=hello&gs_l=hp.3..0l10.3385.5629.1.6345.5.5.0.0.0.0.168.445.4j1.5.0...0.0.qSMjvq4fR4M&psj=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=853bac6d7e512bb7&biw=1440&bih=710
```

Update: The above url works but I need to break it down to a minimum so that I can put my own string together and build my own direct url.

Does anyone know what the minimum required string would be to search google for the work hello would be?

Comment: This question doesn't make much sense... there is no minimum length requirements when you search in Google. You need to elaborate your question better and what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Updated. I want to create my own url so I can add it direct in an anchor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple

```
https://www.google.com/#q=hellooo
```

seems to work for me.